# Dismiss Custom Dialog Problem

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog with a custom layout, and I try to close it when I press a button:

```
private void showAboutDialog() { 

   dialog = new Dialog(MainMenu.this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   dialog.setTitle(R.string.about_title);
   dialog.show();

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)      
   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog,
           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

Button closeButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.about_close_button);
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {      
       public void onClick(View view) { 
       dialog.dismiss();     
       } 
});
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see any errors on LogCat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your listener is not being called.

Replace:

```
Button closeButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.about_close_button);
```

with:

```
Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.about_close_button);
```

and remove the two lines above (`LayoutInflater inflater = ...` and `View layout = ...`).

Comment: +1 for ur help .. it would be great if can please explain y this work and other one doesn't ?

Comment: @MohitSharma It is pretty clear why this works and the OP's code doesn't. The OP is calling `inflater.inflate()` which inflates the layout of his dialog and creates a set of objects that are stored in the variable "layout". He is then setting his listener on an object that has been inflated there. However, when this code is executed: `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);` the dialog is inflating the layout of the dialog itself, creating its own set of objects (one of which is the object that represents the `Button` on the dialog). Calling `findViewById()` on the dialog returns the...

Comment: @MohitSharma ...correct `Button` object (ie: the one that is actually in the dialog on screen). I hope this is clear.